# "Paket ist angekommen" or "Paket ist eingetroffen"?

Tags: word-choice, verb

Is it correct to use the verb ankommen when talking about a parcel that's arrived, or does eintreffen have to be used here?

Comment: Please provide more context, as whom you are addressing with this sentence; in official terms *zustellen* is appropriate as in *Das Paket wurde zugestellt*. Whether it was delivered to your door, whether the neighbour accepted it or it was delivered to a parcel pick-up box may also be relevant.

Comment: Mostly, I'd use "Paket angekommen". And when referring to the contents (or a person), then use "XXX ist eingetroffen".

Comment: So in short: I'd hardly use 'eintreffen' for a parcel, but only for its contents. But 'ankommen' I use for either equally.

Answer (score 6):

Both verbs, "ankommen" and "eintreffen" are fine in this case. I'd consider "eintreffen" to be of a higher register than "ankommen", and use it more with people than with things, but the distinction is not that big.